# dotnet core Subscriber is not being triggered after Publishing

Tags: .net-core, redis, publish-subscribe, stackexchange.redis, subscribe

I'm working on a Redis(StackExchange.Redis) PUBSUB system in Dotnet core and everything works normally until after I publish to my channel. The subscriber simply won't ever be triggered.

Here is my code:

**program.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _ = RunConsumer();
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
```

```
        private static async Task RunConsumer()
        {
            LogWriter logger = new LogWriter();
            IEnvironment envProvider = new EnvironmentProvider();

            try
            {
                ICache cache = new Cache(envProvider);
                IDataRepository dataRepo = new DatabaseRepository();
                PubBusiness publisher = new PubBusiness();
                await publisher.ImportData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await logger.WriteLogErrorAsync($"Exception occurred", ex);
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
        }
```

**Publisher**

```
// ... code that creates my key

// add my data to a batch and save it to redis
batchTasks.Add(batch.ListRightPushAsync("jobs", key));
batch.Execute();
Task.WaitAll(batchTasks.ToArray());

// publishing
ISubscriber sub = _connection.GetSubscriber();
await sub.PublishAsync("uploaded", key);
```

**Subscriber**

```
var db = _connection.GetDatabase();
ISubscriber sub = _connection.GetSubscriber();

// it will never pass here
            await sub.SubscribeAsync("uploaded", async (channel, value) =>
            {
                var key = (await db.ListLeftPopAsync("jobs")).ToString();
               // do my stuff here
            });
```

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1552

Answer (score 0):

Messaging disabled by default, follow the link for details
BUT if short, just enter this command to redis cli to enable all:

> CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events KEA

https://redis.io/docs/manual/keyspace-notifications/#configuration